# Find the $\lim _{z\to 1+i} \frac{z^2-2i}{z^2-2z+2}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

What is the limit of
$$\lim _{z\to 1+i} \frac{z^2-2i}{z^2-2z+2}.$$

Please help

Comment: $z^2-2i = (z-(1+i))(z+(1+i))$ and $z^2-2z+2 = (z-(1+i))(z-(1-i))$. Go figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dividing the numerator and the denominator by $z-1-i$, which works out because they both vanish at $z=1+i$. Thus
$$ z^2 - 2i = (z-1-i)(z+1+i)
\quad\text{and}\quad
z^2-2z+2 = (z-1-i)(z-1+i).
$$
Now cancel the common factor and you can substitute $z=1+i$.

Answer (score 0):

You can factorize both numerator and denominator to remove common factor.

$z^2-2\iota = (z-1-\iota)(z+1+\iota)$ and $z^2-2z+2=(z-1-\iota)(z-1+\iota)$

So $\frac{z^2-2\iota}{z^2-2z+2}=\frac{z+1+\iota}{z-1+\iota}$

You should be able to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\frac{z^2-2i}{z^2-2z+2} =\frac{ (z-(1+i))(z+(1+i))}{(z-(1+i))(z-(1-i))}=\frac{z+(1+i)}{z-(1-i)}$ so that
$$\lim_{z\to (1+i)}\frac{z^2-2i}{z^2-2z+2}=\frac{(1+i)+(1+i)}{(1+i)-(1-i)}=\frac{2+2i}{2i}=-i+1$$